# Error while installing generator-mean-seed

Tags: node.js, npm, yeoman-generator, yeoman-generator-angular, yo

I am trying to follow the instructions given on https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-mean-seed

When i try to run "sudo  npm install -g generator-mean-seed" i get this error

```
npm install -g generator-mean-seed
npm WARN deprecated lodash@1.3.1: lodash@<2.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^3.0.0
npm WARN deprecated CSSselect@0.7.0: the module is now available as 'css-select'
npm WARN deprecated CSSwhat@0.4.7: the module is now available as 'css-what'
npm WARN deprecated lodash@1.2.1: lodash@<2.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^3.0.0
/usr/local/lib
├── generator-mean-seed@1.1.26 
└── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY yo@>=1.0.0

npm WARN generator-mean-seed@1.1.26 requires a peer of yo@>=1.0.0 but none was installed.
```

It says that i need yo installed with version > 1.0.0 but i already have that installed

```
yo --version
1.6.0
```

Any idea on what i am doing wrong or any clue to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem ... the reason seems that the installation of peer dependencies changed in later version of npm. As a workaround, include `yo` when installing `generator-mean-seed` (it doesn't matter it's already installed):

```
$ sudo npm install -g yo generator-mean-seed
```

this way, generator-mean-seed will install correctly:

```
$ sudo npm install -g yo generator-mean-seed
npm WARN deprecated lodash@1.3.1: lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^4.0.0.
npm WARN deprecated CSSselect@0.7.0: the module is now available as 'css-select'
npm WARN deprecated CSSwhat@0.4.7: the module is now available as 'css-what'
npm WARN deprecated lodash@1.2.1: lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^4.0.0.
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@3.0.8: graceful-fs version 3 and before will fail on newer node releases. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible.
npm WARN deprecated npmconf@2.1.2: this package has been reintegrated into npm and is now out of date with respect to npm
/usr/local/bin/yo -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/lib/cli.js

> yo@1.7.0 postinstall /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo
> yodoctor
```